# java log file not found exception

Tags: java, tomcat, slf4j, logback

I am using loback to log and this is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="LOG"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!--See also http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender -->
        <File>
    /logs/tomcat/simulator.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
            <FileNamePattern>/logs/tomcat/simulator.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="my package here" level="DEBUG" />
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="LOG" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

as you see, i am specifying the log file as

`/logs/tomcat/simulator.log`

What i did is creating simulator.log file inside the logs folder in apache tomcat

when i deploy, nothing is being written to that file.

what am i missing?

#### Update

when i log into the logs (catalina.out), i find this exception

```
FileNotFoundException: /logs/tomcat/simulator.log (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Either process have nothing to write on the log file or the process have no permissions for writing.

Comment: @FranMontero are you saying that even though my file is `logs/tomcat/simulator.log` and i create the simulator.log inside `logs` directory, **no tomcat folder inside logs**. and that is no problem? buy why i am getting error file not found? and how to give permission?

Comment: Try with the absolute path to the log file

Comment: @FranMontero what do you mean?

Comment: instead of `/logs/tomcat/simulator.log` try `/all/paths/logs/tomcat/simulator.log`

Comment: @FranMontero no i can't do that. i need to solve my problem without the absolute bath, because i work on mac, the deploy server is linux, my colleague on windows. so i can't do this

Comment: Just give it a try and try with only the filename `simulator.log` too.

Comment: @FranMontero okay obsolete path works, so how can i solve it please using relative path please please

Comment: If `/logs/tomcat/simulator.log` is a path outside tomcat installation, i believe you have to 'navigate' from tomcat dir or use an absolulte path.

Comment: @FranMontero all i need is to log into simulator.log that exists into tomcat/logs folder

Comment: Try with only the name of the log: `<File>simulator.log</File>` it should work.

Comment: @FranMontero lunch time, i will come back after some minutes, thanks for helping